# Halting problem of TM which recognize recursive languages is undecidable?

Tags: formal-languages, turing-machines, undecidability, compilers, turing-completeness

I am preparing for an exam and I came across this question in one of the tests.

> Halting problem of Turing machines which recognize recursive languages
>   is undecidable. (True / False)

The solution given says the statement its False.

But I think the statement is True. Halting problem in itself is undecidable. We can't determine whether the Turing Machine will halt or not.

The test series has a history of wrong answers that's why I am seeking an explanation even if I am wrong.

Edit:
I was looking at the answers and I have trouble understanding the explanations. I know that 'By definition, recursive languages are decideable by Turing machines.'
I will tell you how I breakdown the question. I am given a TM and told that this TM recognizes a recursive language. How do I know that the TM will halt?

Comment: Seems question is not well formulated by the exam.

Comment: I agree with you.

Comment: "I am given a TM and told that this TM recognizes a recursive language." This is redundant. TMs recognize recursive languages by definition.

Comment: But the TM may fall in infinite loop. Can't it?

Comment: @imagine5am no, the whole point of a recursive language- it's very definition- is that the TM won't. Recursive languages are definitionally decidable.

Comment: I understand the definition you are talking about. But what I saying is that how can you say that the TM will hault?

Comment: I maybe going the wrong way with the question. You can also tell me how you are breaking down the question. That would be really helpful.

Comment: @imagine5am Asking "how do you know a Turing Machine will halt on recursive languages" == "how do you know a Turing Machine will halt on decidable languages" == "how do you know a Turing Machine will halt on languages on which it will halt." It's a definition, it's tautological. Recursive languages are definitionally decidable, and decidability definitionally entails that a Turing Machine will halt. Perhaps you are simply unaware of the definition of a recursive language, but any definition will include what I have just stated.

Comment: @imagine5am Turing did not prove that at least one algorithm (Turing Machine) for at least one set of inputs cannot solve the halting problem. He "only" showed that there is no GENERAL algorithm (arbitrary TM) for deciding the halting problem on arbitrary input. Thus there DO exist algorithms (TMs) which can be shown to halt for specific inputs. The set of formal languages which are decidable- i.e. for which an algorithm (TM) can decide if a finite string input belongs in the language or not- is precisely the set of recursive languages.

Comment: @ubadub I think I see your point now. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

By definition, recursive languages are decideable by Turing machines. Thus for recursive languages the TM will always halt.

Comment: Please check out the edit.

Answer (score 1):

If the task is to determine whether a given machine $M$ halts, when you already know that $M$s language is decidable then the answer is always "yes" because every TM that decides a language halts on every input (by definition of "to decide"). Hence, the halting problem on these kind of TMs is decidable.

However, if you want to determine whether the language $$A = \{\langle M \rangle \mid L(M) \text{ is decidable}\}$$ you can find an easy reduction that shows that $A$ is undecidable. I do not think this is the task but it was my first thought reading this question, so maybe it is still useful.

Comment: Please check out the edit in question.